# hosting codeigniter project to linux server

Tags: server, apache2, php

I want to host my CodeIgniter project to Linux server using apache2

I already install apache2 using  `sudo apt install apache2`

I already to copy my project in `/var/www/` and i already set in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` but when I'm open in the browser, the page show `index.html` apache2 it works!

I tried using new conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` but it can't work for me

how I can change that default page to my CodeIgniter project?

Answer (score 0):

- Create Directory for your Project

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/myproject
```

- Set Permissions

```
 sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/project
```

- Add your Project files in `/var/www/myproject`
- Create Virtual Host

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/myproject.conf
```

- Next open your Configuration File

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/myproject.conf
```

- Update your Site URL & Project Root Directory in `myproject.conf` file

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject
```

- Enable Virtual Host

```
sudo a2ensite myproject.conf
```

- Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That's all, Next Point the DNS & check your Site

Comment: that way it can be opened on another network?

Comment: don't touch the Apache Default Configurations Create New Directory and New Conf for your Project Host your files on `/var/www/myproject`

Comment: how if i'll open that project using ip address?